# Loop and increment with while in javascript

Tags: javascript

In need of some help. Javascript isn't my strong point. I'm trying to loop through the following element ids incrementing by 1 on each iteration itself. For example c4_r1_cell_1 would become c4_r2_cell_2, c4_r3_cell_3, etc and so on with each loop through. I need this to happen 6 times with the same increment number per iteration before it goes to the next loop. Where you see "+ loop_count +" needs to be the same number each time before it goes to the next loop run until it hits the last one.

What I don't need is for it to increment each of my "+ loop_count +" like they are separate iterations and it increase them 1,2,3,4,5,6. I need them to be 1,1,1,1,1,1 and then the next loop iteration 2,2,2,2,2,2 etc.

HTML that is being generated:

```
<td><input type="text" id="c1_r<?php echo $i; ?>_cell_2" name="c1_r<?php echo $i; ?>_cell_2" value="<?php echo $row2['c1_r'.$i.'_cell_2']; ?>" /></td>
<td><input type="text" id="c2_r<?php echo $i; ?>_cell_3" name="c2_r<?php echo $i; ?>_cell_3" value="<?php echo $row2['c2_r'.$i.'_cell_3']; ?>" /></td>
<td><input type="text" id="c3_r<?php echo $i; ?>_cell_4" name="c3_r<?php echo $i; ?>_cell_4" value="<?php echo $row2['c3_r'.$i.'_cell_4']; ?>" /></td>
<td><input type="text" id="c4_r<?php echo $i; ?>_cell_5" name="c4_r<?php echo $i; ?>_cell_5" value="<?php echo $row2['c4_r'.$i.'_cell_5']; ?>" /></td>
<td><input type="text" id="c5_r<?php echo $i; ?>_cell_6" name="c5_r<?php echo $i; ?>_cell_6" value="<?php echo $row2['c5_r'.$i.'_cell_6']; ?>" /></td>
```

This is what I have right now that is not working:

```
var loop_count = 1;
while (loop_count < 50) {
document.getElementById("c4_r" + loop_count + "_cell_" + loop_count + "") = 
document.getElementById("c5_r" + loop_count + "_cell_" + loop_count + "");
document.getElementById("c5_r" + loop_count + "_cell_" + loop_count + "") = '';
loop_count++;
}
```

Comment: Your code should do what you explained.

Comment: You can’t assign to a function call. `document.getElementById(`…`) = `…`;` is invalid.

Comment: It's giving the following error in console.

Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Comment: Can you please show your html?

Comment: The code broke to a new line on here. What it's actually doing is copying the value from 1 input to another input hence the = on that line.

Comment: @BeKustom To copy the value, use [`.value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get and set the innerHTML of the DOM elements that you are selecting. As it stands you are trying to select an entire DOM element and assign it to another DOM element - this is something that you can't do. You can however get the innerHTML value of this elements and assign them.

```
var loop_count = 1;
while (loop_count < 50) {
document.getElementById("c4_r" + loop_count + "_cell_" + loop_count).value = document.getElementById("c5_r" + loop_count + "_cell_" + loop_count) ? document.getElementById("c5_r" + loop_count + "_cell_" + loop_count).value : '';
document.getElementById("c5_r" + loop_count + "_cell_" + loop_count).value = '';
loop_count++;
}
```

If you need to check if the DOM element exists, you can just use a simple if statement:

```
var loop_count = 1;
while (loop_count < 50) {
  if (document.getElementById("c4_r" + loop_count + "_cell_" + loop_count)) {
  document.getElementById("c4_r" + loop_count + "_cell_" + loop_count).value = document.getElementById("c5_r" + loop_count + "_cell_" + loop_count) ? document.getElementById("c5_r" + loop_count + "_cell_" + loop_count).value : '';
}
  document.getElementById("c5_r" + loop_count + "_cell_" + loop_count) ? document.getElementById("c5_r" + loop_count + "_cell_" + loop_count).value = '' : undefined;
  loop_count++;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but I have null values in some of the inputs that it will loop over and it through an error Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null is there a way around this?

Comment: @BeKustom - I've updated my answer to include ` || ''` at the end of the first line, which should fix this.

Comment: I tried the updated code it still gives the same error. I would love to use the javascript solution instead of mixing in jQuery if possible.

Comment: @BeKustom do you always have a dom element with that exact id? The error seems to indicate that you don't have that id all the time.

Comment: If those are *inputs*, then you'll want to use `.value` instead of `.innerHTML`!

Comment: @Brett East yes the inputs are created dynamically with a php loop with the exact input id's this loops through.

Comment: Like I said, it would be great to see you html, even if it is just a few lines. This can be done quite easily without jQuery, but as @Bergi points out, depending on your element will change how it is written.

Comment: @BrettEast I updated the original post with the HTML code that is being generated.

Comment: @BeKustom I updated my answer to use `.value` instead, give it a go. You can also check if the element exists and only change it if it does.

Comment: Thank you and @Bergi for getting me straightened out.

Comment: No worries @BeKustom , it's a little verbose still, but you could assign your selections to variables to clean that up.

Answer (score 0):

I modified a bit to give a context hopefully the underlying logic should be what you are looking for: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/drpeck/3r89rv7w/) below is a snippet of plain Javascript:

```
var loop_count = 1;  //*variable initialization*
while(loop_count<50){    //*iterator and the condition*   
 var text=document.getElementById("c4_r" + loop_count + "_cell_" + loop_count + "").innerHTML;   // *assigning to a a new variable the content of the element matching the ID*
loop_count++; }     //variable increment to meet stop iteration when at 50 and closure of the while.
```

Comment: It's what I'm looking for logically, but will it account for possible null values in some of the inputs it iterates over?

Comment: What do you want it to happen if it sees a null value? I would add an 'if(foo){code}'  to define this action.

Answer (score -1):

try this way. it helps you

```
var loop_count = 1;
while (loop_count < 50) {

    $('#c4_r' + loop_count + '_cell_' + loop_count + '').val($('#c5_r' + loop_count + '_cell_' + loop_count + '').val());
    $('#c5_r' + loop_count + '_cell_' + loop_count + '').val('');

    loop_count++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @neeraj this way does work by mixing in jQuery.

Comment: @BeKustom - see my answer if you don't want to mix in jquery